# Actor in Service Fabric Mesh not working - Unable to load DLL FabricRuntime.dll

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm looking at Service Fabric Mesh. Built an ASP.NETCORE API app so far - which runs fine.

Now I'm trying to add a (scheduled) Actor in a new project as described in [this tutorial](https://dajbych.net/azure-service-fabric-scheduled-tasks). All builds well but on start-up I get the followin exception at:

```
private static void Main()
{
try
{
   ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<SchedulingActor>((context, actorType) => new SchedulingActorService<ISchedulingActor>(context, actorType)).Wait();
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
}
```

`System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorRuntime' threw an exception.'`

`InnerException: DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FabricRuntime.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From recent [announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-service-fabric-mesh-is-now-in-public-preview/) of SF MESH, they said actors framework is not supported on MESH yet, and will be in a future releases because it requires access to the underlying platform resources not available in MESH.

> SF Mesh is a multi-tenant service and so does not allow any access to the underlying VMs and all the deployments into SF Mesh are in containers. Services using actors, have dependencies that need access to the Nodes, and so currently there is no easy way to deploy them to SF Mesh, however providing a way for the customers to migrate their services from the SF clusters to SF mesh is in the roadmap and is planned to land prior to GA.

PS: This is said in the Q&A at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Ah thanks. I did check the FAQs but not the comments section.